# Getting specific ansible facts in a list

Tags: ansible, vmware, ansible-facts

I am currently attempting to automatically create anti-affinity rules for deploying various apps in VMware. I've been using the drs_rule module like so:

```
- name: Create DRS Anti-Affinity Rule for appX
  vmware_vm_vm_drs_rule:
    hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
    username: '{{ vcenter_username }}'
    password: '{{ vcenter_password }}'
    cluster_name: '{{ vsphere_cluster }}'
    enabled: True
    vms:
      -appXa
      -appXb
      -appXc
    drs_rule_name: appX_rule
    mandatory: True
    affinity_rule: False
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: True
```

However, the exact number of VMs can vary based on the deployment. Therefore, I need to be able to pull this information dynamically. This is closest I can find to what I need:

```
- name: Create DRS Anti-Affinity Rule for appX
  vmware_vm_vm_drs_rule:
    hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
    username: '{{ vcenter_username }}'
    password: '{{ vcenter_password }}'
    cluster_name: '{{ vsphere_cluster }}'
    enabled: True
    vms: "{{ item }}"
    drs_rule_name: appX_rule
    mandatory: True
    affinity_rule: False
  loop: "{{ groups['appX'] }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: True
```

While this does pull the IP addresses from my inventory file for that group, I need to pull the VM names (i.e. hostnames) in order for it to work with this module. Is there a way to make something like this work within the playbook? Basically to have it return a list of hostname strings, so I can plug it into this module.

```
# ansible appX-i inventory -m setup -a "filter=ansible_hostname"

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_hostname": "appXa"
    },
    "changed": false
}
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_hostname": "appXb"
    },
    "changed": false
}
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_hostname": "appXc"
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

Much obliged :-)

**EDIT: I was able to extract the hostname. Credit goes to mdaniel for that**

```
- name: Create DRS Anti-Affinity Rule for appX
  vmware_vm_vm_drs_rule:
    hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
    username: '{{ vcenter_username }}'
    password: '{{ vcenter_password }}'
    cluster_name: '{{ vsphere_cluster }}'
    enabled: True
    vms: "{{ item }}"
    drs_rule_name: appX_rule
    mandatory: True
    affinity_rule: False
    loop: "{{ groups['appX'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_hostname') }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: True
```

However, we actually need the items in the format of "hostname_IP" e.g. "appXa_192.168.1.100". Is there a way to pull the IP address and concatenate an underscore in between them all on the same line?

Also, having some issues pulling the IPs with map/extract since the ansible facts have them in dictionary format. I.e.

```
"ansible_default_ipv4": {
  "address": "192.169.1.100",
```

I could use ansible_all_ipv4_addresses which is in a list, but that could introduce complications if we ever attach multiple IPs to the same machines.

Comment: I'm pretty sure [`| map("extract", hostvars, "ansible_hostname")`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, we actually need the items in the format of "hostname_IP" e.g. "appXa_192.168.1.100". Is there a way to pull the IP address and concatenate an underscore in between them all on the same line?

Yes and no; doing it in one shot would be some silliness, since there is no `lambda:` equivalent in jinja2, but using the [`with_together:` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/together_lookup.html) will likely do what you want, since it will give the task access to the hostname, the matching ip, and then allow you to cheaply join them *together* as needed. The `together` lookup should be safe to use to pair them up since (as far as I know) `groups["appX"]` is ordered deterministically and thus each `map` application will happen to the same list

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: |
      the hostname is '{{ item.0 }}'
      its IP is '{{ item.1 }}'
      composite key is '{{ item.0 ~ "_" ~ item.1 }}'
  with_together:
  - '{{ groups["appX"] | map("extract", hostvars, "ansible_hostname") | list }}'
  - '{{ groups["appX"] | map("extract", hostvars, ["ansible_default_ipv4", "address"]) | list }}'
```